# Are bulk inserts less system intensive than multple single inserts?

Tags: mysql, bulkinsert

I have about 50 scripts on a server inserting between 3 and 6 sets of data every second. I am finding that MySQL is in turn hogging all system resources and sometimex it crashes the server.

I was thinking that if I collect 5 minutes worth of queries and do 1 bulk insert per script it would help but will it help by a small margin or a big one? Does anyone have any experience switching to bulk inserts?

My Tables are MyISAM (can change them if neccessary and if I won't lose data).
MySQL Version: 5.1.56

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be a definite noticeable difference. With bulk you are changing from many database open,query,close to a single open, many queries and close. If you want to limit the load further simply write a lot of them to a flat file and have a cron job process that file into the database at off-peak times

Answer (score 2):

Bulk inserts are much faster. But in this case you should care about query length; the length has to be less then [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) - *the maximum size of one packet or any generated/intermediate string*.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

- Do bulk inserts e.g. `INSERT INTO ... VALUES (...),(...),(...);`
- Make stored procedures as bulk insert. So you insert in maybe sets of 10 or 20. `bulk(a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3);`
- Hack: Make a table of type Blackhole. Insert by stored procedure. Create a trigger on that table that just inserts into the real table. (It works and is very fast!)